# How to automatically set number of rows & columns subplots

Tags: python, loops, automation, subplot

I have a certain amount of figures I want to generate and organize in subplots, and I would like to automatically find the amount of columns and rows to specify in my subplots. So far the best way I found was to calculate the square root of my total amount of subplots, round it to the upper int, and automatically delete the empty subplots. But this method is not the best when the amount of subplots increases. Do you know of a better way to do this ?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt


percentile = np.linspace(0.1,0.9,10)
test = np.linspace(0,10,123)
nb = int(np.sqrt(len(percentile))) + 1

# the "test" variable is not important. The "percentile" dictates how many subplots I want

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nb,nb, figsize=(15, 15), facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

count = 0
for l in range(0,nb):
    for c in range(0,nb):
            
            if count < len(percentile):            
                axs[l,c].plot(test*percentile[count])

            else:
                axs[l,c].set_visible(False)
            
            count = count + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For a given number of subplots it would be nice to not leave any blank subplots and have a relatively square shaped grid of subplots. For many numbers of subplots the pair of closest together factors gives you the most square shape to your grid without leaving any blank subplots.

```py
def close_factors(number):
    ''' 
    find the closest pair of factors for a given number
    '''
    factor1 = 0
    factor2 = number
    while factor1 +1 <= factor2:
        factor1 += 1
        if number % factor1 == 0:
            factor2 = number // factor1
        
    return factor1, factor2
```

In this case factor 1 will always be wider than factor 2 so the programmer can decide if they prefer width or height first.

But this will not give a very square grid of subplots in the case where a number is prime or at least has no sets of factors close together.
In this case it may be desirable to leave some subplots as blank plots at the end of the grid in exchange for a more square-ish set of subplots.

```py
def almost_factors(number):
    '''
    find a pair of factors that are close enough for a number that is close enough
    '''
    while True:
        factor1, factor2 = close_factors(number)
        if 1/2 * factor1 <= factor2: # the fraction in this line can be adjusted to change the threshold aspect ratio
            break
        number += 1
    return factor1, factor2
```